# Adding logs within a wrapped function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have created a function wrapper to help give me various print statements:

```js
function fnWrapper(fn, verbosity=false) {
    return function(...rest) {
        if (verbosity) console.log(`Calling "${fn.name}(${rest})"`)
        const res = fn(...rest); // possible to add debugging **within** this wrapped function?
        if (verbosity) console.log('==>', res)
        return res;
    }
}
function add(x,y) {
     return x===0 ? y : add(x-1, y+1);
}
const add2 = fnWrapper(add, true);

add2(2,3);
// Calling "add(2,3)"
// ==> 5
```

Is it possible to add debugging within the function itself, for example, at its most basic to translate a function such as the following:

```
function something(x,y) {
    console.log(arguments); // add this in
    ...
}
```

So for the above function it would make the `add` become:

```
function add(x,y) {
    console.log(arguments);
    return x===0 ? y : add(x-1, y+1);
}
```

If so, how could that be done?

Comment: What would doing this provide that a wrapper doesn't? Note that it is in general impossible to modify the source of a function at runtime in Javascript.

Comment: @NickBailey it could help to illustrate the recursive calls to the function

Comment: That makes sense. I don't think you can do what you want to without some sort of preprocessor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible, you cannot change what a function does.

The problem is that `add` calls `add`, and `add2` also calls `add` only. You can however simply **replace** `add`:

```js
function fnWrapper(fn, verbosity=false) {
    return function(...rest) {
        if (verbosity) console.log(`Calling "${fn.name}(${rest})"`)
        const res = fn.call(this, ...rest);
        if (verbosity) console.log('==>', res)
        return res;
    }
}
function add(x,y) {
     return x===0 ? y : add(x-1, y+1);
}
add = fnWrapper(add, true); /*
^^^ */

add(2,3);
```

Comment: oh wow, such a simple approach, that's great, thank you.

Comment: You can also use this without the intermediate function declaration and reassignment at the price of a bit more syntactic complexity:  `const add2 = fnWrapper ((x, y) => x === 0 ? y : add2 (x - 1, y + 1), true)`.  That verbosity level appearing later bothers me, but you can't put it up front if it's optional.  An alternative would be a version that partially applies the verbosity and returns the rest and then you can just do `const logVerbose = fnWrapper (true); const add = logVerbose ((x, y) => ...)`.